# how to change a complete line with sed c option

Tags: sed

The sed command below is supposed to change the country for Sergio Oliva to Cuba from USA, but as you can see in the output that it's still USA.  The book I'm using uses this example to illustrate using the `c` option to change a complete line. Can you explain why this example is not working as intended.

command

`sed '/\<Oliva\>/ c \
Sergio Oliva Cuba 1967 1968 1969' mrolympia.dat`

output

```
Larry Scott USA 1965 1966
 Sergio Oliva USA 1967 1968 1969
 Arnold Schwarzenegger Osterreich 1970 1971 1972 1973 1974 1975
 Franco Columu Argentinien 1976 1981
 Chris Dickerson USA 1982
 Samir Bannout Libanon 1984
 Lee Haney USA 1984 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991
 Dorian Yates Grossbritannien 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997
 Ronnie Coleman USA 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004
```

Comment: What is the output of `sed --version`?

Comment: I believe the reason why is because you forgot to add the `-e 's/pattern/replacement/` after sed

Comment: @Ramesh I ran that on a Mac, it didn't give any output about the version, only that it was an illegal option to pass to sed. Sed things I'm trying to run sed rather than ask its version. In short, I'm not sure what version it is.

Comment: @ryekayo I ran it your way and got same result i.e. `sed -e '/\<Oliva\>/ c \ `

Comment: @Leahcim, I tried it in my system and it worked. I have `GNU sed version 4.2.1` in my machine. So I suspect the replacement is not working because of version, may be.

Comment: Possibly your version of `sed` isn't recognizing the `\<` and `\>`. What happens if you change the first part of your command to `sed '/ Oliva / c …`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your `sed` version, but my suspicion is that it doesn't support those word barrier markers:

```
sed '/ Oliva /c\
Sergio Oliva Cuba 1967 1968 1969
' <<\DATA
Larry Scott USA 1965 1966
Sergio Oliva USA 1967 1968 1969
Arnold Schwarzenegger Osterreich 1970 1971 1972 1973 1974 1975
Franco Columu Argentinien 1976 1981
Chris Dickerson USA 1982
Samir Bannout Libanon 1984
Lee Haney USA 1984 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991
Dorian Yates Grossbritannien 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997
Ronnie Coleman USA 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Larry Scott USA 1965 1966 
Sergio Oliva Cuba 1967 1968 1969
Arnold Schwarzenegger Osterreich 1970 1971 1972 1973 1974 1975
Franco Columu Argentinien 1976 1981
Chris Dickerson USA 1982
Samir Bannout Libanon 1984
Lee Haney USA 1984 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991
Dorian Yates Grossbritannien 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997
Ronnie Coleman USA 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004
```

You see - those barriers can only serve to handle both space and/or newline on either side. But your input always has spaces on either side of *Oliva* so... just do away with them?

Also, if you just want to change Cuba, then, you *could* just change Cuba:

```
sed 's/Oliva USA/Oliva Cuba/'
```